# MySQL Syntax Error inserting from <textarea> into type VARCHAR(999) <<< resolved was using improper table name

Tags: mysql

Getting a MySQL error message when I try to insert a text message from a  form element into my database setup to receive as type VARCHAR with a max 999 characters. I also tried setting type as TEXT. Perhaps there is something I'm just not seeing here. Error states its a syntax error, but I don't see one. I'm using MySQL ver 5.1

Error message reads:

"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'key (number, category, question, answertxt, answer, correct, incorrect, feedback' at line 1".

Here is my submitting form (create.php):

```
    <?php

    session_start(); //start sesson.

    $error = false;
    $error = $_SESSION['error'];

    if($error){
        echo '<div class="error">Please fill in all required fields indicated by the * symbol</div>';
    }

    ?>

    <form action="db_adddata.php" method="post">

    <label>Category</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="category" name="category" value="" maxlength="50">*<br>

    <label>Question text</label><br>
    <textarea id="question" name="question" rows="7" cols="20"></textarea>*<br>

    <label>Answer text</label><br>
    <textarea id="answertxt" name="answertxt" rows="7" cols="20"></textarea>*<br>

    <label>Accepted  answers (comma separated)</label><br>
    <textarea id="answer" name="answer" rows="7" cols="20"></textarea>*<br>

    <label>Correct answer response</label><br>
    <textarea id="correct" name="correct" rows="7" cols="20"></textarea>*<br>

    <label>Incorrect answer response</label><br>
    <textarea id="incorrect" name="incorrect" rows="7" cols="20"></textarea>*<br>

    <label>Feedback response</label><br>
    <textarea id="feedback" name="feedback" rows="7" cols="20"></textarea>*<br>

    <label>Lesson refferal response</label><br>
    <textarea id="lessonref" name="lessonref" rows="7" cols="20"></textarea>*<br>

    <input type="submit" value="submit">

    </form>
```

And here is the processing script (db_adddata.php):

```
    <?php

session_start(); //start sesson.
require('db_connect.php'); //connect to the database.

//assign variables with the data we posted from the form on the previous page.

$category = $_POST['category'];
$question = $_POST['question'];
$answertxt = $_POST['answertxt'];
$answer = $_POST['answer'];
$correct = $_POST['correct'];
$incorrect = $_POST['incorrect'];
$feedback = $_POST['feedback'];
$lessonref = $_POST['lessonref'];

//assign vars to session vars.

$_SESSION['category'] = $category;
$_SESSION['question'] = $question;
$_SESSION['answertxt'] = $answertxt;
$_SESSION['answer'] = $answer;
$_SESSION['correct'] = $correct;
$_SESSION['incorrect'] = $incorrect;
$_SESSION['feedback'] = $feedback;
$_SESSION['lessonref'] = $lessonref;


//check if vars are empty if yes deny and go to error page. Otherwise continue.

if(empty($category) || empty($question) || empty($answertxt) || empty($answer) || empty($correct) || empty($incorrect) || empty($feedback) || empty($lessonref)) {

    $_SESSION['error'] = true; //set error as true.
    header('Location: create.php'); //go back to form page.

}
else {

    //add the data to the database.

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO key (number, category, question, answertxt, answer, correct, incorrect, feedback, lessonref, datemod) VALUES ('','$category','$question','$answertxt','$answer','$correct','$incorrect','$feedback','$lessonref',CURDATE())")or die(mysql_error());

    header('Location: viewkey.php'); // go to view key page.
}

mysql_close(); //close connection.

    ?>
```

Below is a info of my MySQL table info for table named 'key':

Field     |  Type        |  Collation        |  EXTRA

---

number    | int(6)       |                   | AUTO_INCREMENT (primary)

---

category  | varchar(999) | latin1_general_ci |

---

question  | varchar(999) | latin1_general_ci |

---

answertxt | varchar(999) | latin1_general_ci |

---

answer    | varchar(999) | latin1_general_ci |

---

correct   | varchar(999) | latin1_general_ci |

---

incorrect | varchar(999) | latin1_general_ci |

---

feedback  | varchar(999) | latin1_general_ci |

---

lessonref | varchar(999) | latin1_general_ci |

---

datemod   | date         |                   |

---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`key` is a reserved word in mySQL. You need to surround that table with backticks:

```
INSERT HIGH_PRIORITY INTO `key` ... etc
```

Comment: Thanks soo much Marcus I changed to `key` now I get error: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'key' at line 1"

Comment: I'm going to try simply renaming my table from key to somethig else. I'll report back in a few. Many thanks.

Comment: Looks like you're using regular quotes.

Comment: Changng my table name from reserved word key to testdata worked! issue resolved. thanks to Marcus and Katai!

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `` around 'key'

like this:

```
INSERT HIGH_PRIORITY INTO `key` (number, category, question, answertxt, answer, correct, incorrect, feedback, lessonref, datemod) 
VALUES ('','$category','$question','$answertxt','$answer','$correct','$incorrect','$feedback','$lessonref',CURDATE())
```

Should work